# Create a Chrome extension that runs server-side

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is it possible to develop a server-side extension? Using NodeJS for example, I would like to give some protection to my JS code so that it os not visible or subject to change, or maybe you have another alternative for what I want.

Comment: I am fairly certain that that is not possible. You can minify it to make it harder to steal, or use ajax calls to run code on your server.   
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: thanks, ajax calls may works for me, i'll test it.